# how to set required android and mac version flutter

Tags: android, flutter

how can i  set the required version of Android and Mac along with larger versions?

for example i want set requried version to Android 7 and IOS 10 and over version than these

Has anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

For Android :

- Go to  `project_folder/android/app/build.gradle`
- Find the `defaultConfig` section update the `minSdkVersion` to the new version.
- run the `flutter clean` command.
- `flutter pub get && flutter run`

For IOS :

- Set MinimumOSVersion to 10.0 in ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
- uncomment platform :ios, '10.0' in ios/Podfile
- `ios/Podfile` should  contains the following post install script:

`post_install do |installer|`
  `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`
     `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)`
        `target.build_configurations.each do |config|`
        `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'`
     `end`
   `end`
`end`

Than you can run this command on your terminal.

```
  flutter clean \
        && rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock \
        && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace \
```